# How to implement "Exclusive Consumer" or "Exclusive Queue" with Celery and Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to implement kind of "Exclusive Consumer" or "Exclusive Queues" which avoids the end user having to pin anything: the broker will pick a single Message-Consumer to get all the messages for a queue to ensure **ordering**, and if that consumer fails, the broker will auto failover and choose another consumer.

I wondered if a combination of Celery and RabbitMQ can make it.

Answer (score 2):

Despite realising that this question is more than 7 years old, someone may stumble across this page as I just did. So, in 2019, RabbitMQ team has released a version 3.8 which supports new feature called "Single Active Consumer". It offers exactly that type of consumer-exclusivity combined with automatic fallback behavior, where the next (randomly chosen) consumer listening to the queue will be made the "single active consumer" upon the first consumer falling off or disconnecting for any reason. And this feature does not require any complicated setup of the message queue itself; it works with almost any queue.

Read more at https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2019-04-23-rabbitmq-3-8-feature-focus-single-active-consumer.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer

Answer (score 0):

Though RabbitMQ has the concept of "exclusive" queues, I do not think you can get the fallback behavior that you need.

The broker will not "choose" a single consumer. Failure modes can be addressed by not using auto-ACK, rejecting on error and letting your worker die/restart.

This preserves message order if there is only one consumer. With load-balancing your mileage might vary.